# Process in git-bash.exe cannot open `CONIN$`

Tags: windows, go, msys2

When I launch a `cli.exe` in `git-bash.exe` which tries to open the terminal of the process on Windows (open file `CONIN$`) it does not work: (here in Go)

```golang
// GetCtty gets the file descriptor of the controlling terminal.
// Taken from:
// https://github.com/mattn/go-tty/blob/master/tty_windows.go
func GetCtty() (*os.File, error) {
    in, err := syscall.Open("CONIN$", syscall.O_RDWR, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return os.NewFile(uintptr(in), "/dev/tty"), nil
}
```

`GetCtty()` return an error, meaning there is no such thing?
Why? In all other cirumstances that works, WSL bash (execute .exe), Powershell, Cmd, VS Code Integrated Terminal with (bash.exe from git-for-windows...)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. Using this program:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "syscall"
)

func main() {
   _, err := syscall.Open("CONIN$", syscall.O_RDWR, 0)
   fmt.Println(err)
}
```

With just PowerShell I get this:

```
PS C:\> .\open.exe
<nil>
```

Then with MSYS2 Bash, I get this:

```
PS C:\> bash.exe
bash-5.1$ ./open.exe
<nil>
```

Personally if Windows is going to be your "daily driver", I would recommend not using `git-bash.exe`, or WSL. Go is not like C, where you have all these supporting Makefiles and Shell scripts in the build process. For the most part, you just write Go code, then use the Go compiler to compile it. So I have discovered that Bash doesn't really need to be involved in the process, and I just use PowerShell now. If you really need Bash for some other reason, you can
install the MSYS2 Bash package:

https://packages.msys2.org/package/bash

Comment: Ehm -> The problem is here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46681